# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet HelloServlet is not available using apache tomcat 6

Tags: servlets

```
Apr 28, 2012 3:48:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /hello
  delegate: false
  repositories:
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6eb38a
 HelloServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 28, 2012 3:48:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet HelloServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 28, 2012 3:48:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: Servlet HelloServlet is currently unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the $TOMCAT_HOME$/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes folder, does this have a compiled version of your HelloServlet (HelloServlet.class).

What's the fully qualified package name of your HelloServlet class - You need to make sure your web.xml referenced the fully qualified name (if your HelloServlet has the package definition of x.y.x, then web.xml needs to reference `x.y.z.HelloServlet`)

Comment: My HelloServlet.class file is in webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/HelloServlet.class.

Comment: I had wrote in the tag<servlet-class>hello.HelloServlet<servlet-class> it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Your class needs to be in `webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/hello/HelloServlet.class`

Comment: Packageless servlets works in old Tomcat versions only.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to you web.xml file in the project.

2 - See the tag `<servlet-class>` and make sure that this should be in the following format. `eclipsePackage.JavaClass`.

The problem is very descriptive, that it is unable to load the specified class because it couldn't `locate` it. the location comes from `web.xml` . make sure the path is correct in the mentioned tab.